# If $m = g \circ f$ in a dagger category and $m$ is an isometry, is it possible that $f$ fails to be an isometry?

Tags: category-theory, dagger-categories

**Question.** Suppose $m : A \rightarrow B$ is an isometry in a dagger category (by which I mean that $m^\dagger \circ m=\mathrm{id}_A$), and that we're given arrows $f : A \rightarrow Y$ and $g : Y \rightarrow B$ such that $m = g \circ f$. Is it possible that $f$ fails to be an isometry?

The remainder of the question is motivation...

In category theory, we have the following well-known result.

**Proposition.** Suppose $m : A \rightarrow B$ is a split monomorphism, and that we're given arrows $f : A \rightarrow Y$ and $g : Y \rightarrow B$ such that $m = g \circ f$. Then $f$ is a split monomorphism.

*Proof.* Since $m$ splits, let $e : B \rightarrow A$ satisfy $e \circ m = \mathrm{id}_A$. Then defining $e' = e \circ g$, we see that $$e' \circ f = (e \circ g) \circ f = e \circ m = \mathrm{id}_A.$$

Unfortunately, if we're in a dagger category and we try replacing "split monomorpism" by "isometry", the above proof doesn't seem to go through. In particular, although we can show that $f$ is a split monomorphism by defining $e' = m^\dagger \circ g$, there appears to be no guarantee that $f^\dagger$ equals $m^\dagger \circ g$.

Comment: Have you checked this in the category of Hilbert spaces?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, no; I don't know the first thing about Hilbert spaces! Are you suggesting there is an easy counterexample there?

Comment: I suggest that you think about examples before asking general category theory stuff. And then tell us what happens in these examples, so that we don't have to do this and can check other examples.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, that's fair. To make a small contribution: it holds in $\mathrm{Rel}.$ The isometries are precisely the relations $f : X \rightarrow Y$ such that, firstly, for all $x \in X$ we have that $f(x)$ is non-empty, and secondly, for all distinct $x,x' \in X$ we have that $f(x),f(x')$ are disjoint. I'll try to include some examples next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample: let $m$ be the identity and pick $f$ and $g$ any inverses that aren't daggers of each other. For example in the dagger category of complex matrices with conjugate transpose:

$$m=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\
0&1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$f=\begin{pmatrix}1/2&0\\
0&2\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$g=\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\
0&1/2\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Or even $m=1$, $f=1/2$ and $g=2$.